# Loading complicated excel using pandas.read_excel

Tags: python, pandas, io, ipython, import-from-excel

I'm newbie in python and especially in pandas and I'm trying to load excel file which has heading like that:

`0 |  first  |         | ...
1 | column  | column2 | ...
2 | name    |         | ...`

where 0, 1, 2 - indexes or rows in file, and I'm trying to load it into a padas.DataFrame like this:

```
dataset = pandas.read_excel('dataset.xls')
```

and dataset has columns with names ['first', Unnamed: 1, ...], but I want to load it so that it had heading ['first column name', 'column2', ...].

Is there any standard way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is no standrd way of doing this, since it's not a usual operation. But you can easily achieve it in few steps:

1) Read first 3 rows from you excel-file.

2) Construct column names from them.

3) Read excel-file without creating header, skipping first 3 rows (and first column if needed).

4) Redefine column names of your DataFrame using the result you got on step 2.